# C# Queue and Enumerator with 2 threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have 2 thread:

Thread A: it puts items in the queue

```
toDoReuqests.Enqueue(item);
```

Thread B: it gets items from the queue

```
var iterator = toDoReuqests.GetEnumerator();
while ( iterator.MoveNext() )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Tolto dalla coda B");
    Console.WriteLine(iterator.Current.id);
}
```

Is it the correct way to remove items from the queue? Can multithread give me an error on the enumerator?

Comment: You should just use `ConcurrentQueue<>` and be done with it

Comment: Thank you all! You've been fast and clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will have problems with 2 threads and simple Queue. Advice - use [ConcurrentQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx). It's thread safe.

Thread A:

```
toDoReuqests.Enqueue("test");
```

Thread B:

```
string retValue;

while(!toDoReuqests.TryDequeue(out retValue))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Tolto dalla coda B");
    Console.WriteLine(retValue);    
}
```

For removing items from queue use methods Dequeue or TryDequeue.

Comment: this is my favorite answer. Thanks! (also for question formatting)

Comment: You might want to do a `BlockingCollection<T>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will *not* remove items from the queue, it will simply iterate them. You need to do something like this:

```
while ( queue.Count > 0 )
{
    var current = queue.Dequeue();
    Console.WriteLine("Tolto dalla coda B");
    Console.WriteLine(current);
}
```

Also, the code is not thread-safe, you'll either need a thread-safe implementation of `queue`, or guard it with [locks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx)